# Print a log item every hour from a specified date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to print datetime every hour for the last 5 years. I am trying to create a mock data.

```
For example
dd/mm/yyyy hh
```

Please advice how i can achieve this

Comment: Use a date setted to now - 5 years and loop adding an hour until your date is now. moment can be useful

Comment: currentDate=new Date(); , oldDate=new Date('01-01-2010'); , iterate and use Date class to create old dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the time 5 years back. Iterate by adding one hour at the end of every iteration and continue until you get to the current time.

Here below is the code that will start from exactly 5 years before current time and continue until current time.

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var startTime = new Date();

startTime.setFullYear(currentTime.getFullYear() - 5);

for(var time = startTime; time <= currentTime; time.setHours(time.getHours() + 1)) {
    console.log(time);
}
```

Hope this helps you.